# AnimateMotion не работает должным образом

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

Я хочу, чтобы темные синие точки двигались с одинаковой скоростью, при одинаковой продолжительности, но одна  точка, немного отстает.

Также я хочу, чтобы после круга логотипа все точки объединились, как будто это одна большая точка, и затем переместились к иконке ноутбука.

Вот это то, что я пробовал .. Просьба помочь

```css
.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #303D4F;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.st1 {
  fill: #21A8E0;
}

.st2 {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
}

.st3 {
  font-family: 'Lato-Light';
}

.st4 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.st5 {
  fill: #303D4F;
  stroke: #303D4F;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.st6 {
  fill: #6EC5E0;
}

.st7 {
  fill: #DDE9F1;
}

.st8 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #303D4F;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.st9 {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
  stroke: #303D4F;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.st10 {
  fill: #FAFBFC;
  stroke: #303D4F;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.st11 {
  fill: #303D4F;
}

path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1093.92, 1093.92;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-duration: 2.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 970 570">
<g>
 <g>
  <path class="st0" d="M467.9,306.3H150.1c-11.9,0-21.6,9.7-21.6,21.6v74.5" id="path-to-trace-6"/>
  <path class="st0" d="M467.9,263.6H185.8c-11.9,0-21.6-9.7-21.6-21.6V101.8" id="path-to-trace-1"/>
  <path class="st0" d="M467.9,284.7H120.3c-11.9,0-21.6-9.7-21.6-21.6V222" id="path-to-trace-2"/>
  <path class="st0" d="M280.7,165.9v70.3c0,4,3.2,7.2,7.2,7.2h180.1l35.9,51.8" id="path-to-trace-3"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M0,0h204.6" id="last-path"></path>
  <line fill="none" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="440.3" y1="295.2" x2="819" y2="295.2"></line>
  <g>
   <path class="st1" d="M139.5,201.8c0,11-9,20-20,20H78c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h41.6c11,0,20,9,20,20V201.8z"/>
  </g>
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 80.6445 205.3301)" class="st2 st3 st4">Trade</text>
  <g>
   <path class="st1" d="M213.1,425.8c0,11-9,20-20,20h-92.1c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h92.1c11,0,20,9,20,20V425.8z"/>
  </g>
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 110.1387 429.3643)" class="st2 st3 st4">Derivatives</text>
  <g>
   <path class="st1" d="M359.7,146.8c0,11-9,20-20,20H218c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h121.7c11,0,20,9,20,20V146.8z"/>
  </g>
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 220.1895 150.3301)" class="st2 st3 st4">Macro-economics</text>
  <g>
   <path class="st1" d="M250.6,83c0,11-9,20-20,20H97.8c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h132.9c11,0,20,9,20,20V83z"/>
  </g>
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 101.3477 86.4922)" class="st2 st3 st4">Supply v/s demand</text>
  <path class="st0" d="M467.9,327.4H248.2c-11.9,0-21.6,9.7-21.6,21.6v119.2" id="path-to-trace-4"/>
  <g>
   <path class="st1" d="M307.5,491.5c0,11-9,20-20,20H165.7c-11,0-20-9-20-20V487c0-11,9-20,20-20h121.7c11,0,20,9,20,20V491.5z"/>
  </g>
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 167.916 495.042)" class="st2 st3 st4">Financial markets</text>
  <g>
   <path class="st1" d="M367.4,408.7c0,11-9,20-20,20h-84.8c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h84.8c11,0,20,9,20,20V408.7z"/>
  </g>
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 267.4238 412.1934)" class="st2 st3 st4">Geo politics</text>
  <path class="st0" d="M467.9,347.7H311c-4,0-7.2,3.2-7.2,7.2v29.4" id="path-to-trace-5"/>
  <circle fill="#313c50" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
    <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"  keyPoints="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto">
         <mpath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path-to-trace-1"></mpath>
       </animateMotion>
   </circle>
   <circle fill="#313c50" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
     <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto">
         <mpath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path-to-trace-2"></mpath>
       </animateMotion>
   </circle>
   <circle fill="#313c50" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
     <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto">
         <mpath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path-to-trace-3"></mpath>
       </animateMotion>
   </circle>
   <circle fill="#313c50" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
    <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto">
         <mpath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path-to-trace-6"></mpath>
       </animateMotion>
   </circle>
   <circle fill="#313c50" cx=" " cy="" r="6.7">
    <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto">
         <mpath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path-to-trace-4"></mpath>
       </animateMotion>
   </circle>
   <circle fill="#313c50" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
    <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto" id="smallCircle">
         <mpath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path-to-trace-5"></mpath>
       </animateMotion>
   </circle>
   <circle class="st5" cx="" cy="" r="11.2">
    <animateMotion begin="smallCircle.end-0.5s" dur="4s" calcMode="linear" id="bigCircle">
            <mpath xlink:href="#last-path"></mpath>
          </animateMotion>
   </circle>
  <g>
   <circle class="st6" cx="503.9" cy="292" r="79.4"/>
   <g>
    <path class="st2" d="M478.4,276.5l-0.2,1.8c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.7c-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.5-0.4,0.7l-18.1,24.8h15.2l-0.6,4.7h-23
     l0.2-1.8c0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.7c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.5,0.4-0.7l18.2-24.9h-14.5l0.6-4.7H478.4z"/>
    <path class="st2" d="M494,309.3c-0.7,0-1.2-0.2-1.4-0.5c-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.7-0.4-1.2l0.2-3.4c-1.1,1.7-2.4,3-3.8,4
     c-1.4,1-2.9,1.5-4.4,1.5c-1,0-1.8-0.2-2.6-0.5c-0.8-0.4-1.5-0.9-2-1.6c-0.6-0.7-1-1.6-1.3-2.7c-0.3-1.1-0.5-2.4-0.5-3.9
     c0-1.3,0.1-2.6,0.4-3.9c0.3-1.3,0.7-2.5,1.2-3.6c0.5-1.1,1.1-2.2,1.8-3.1c0.7-1,1.5-1.8,2.3-2.5c0.8-0.7,1.7-1.2,2.7-1.6
     c1-0.4,2-0.6,3-0.6c1,0,2,0.2,2.8,0.6c0.8,0.4,1.6,0.9,2.2,1.5l1.5-12.2h5.5l-4.1,33.7H494z M486.3,305.2c0.6,0,1.2-0.2,1.9-0.6
     c0.6-0.4,1.2-1,1.8-1.7c0.6-0.7,1.1-1.6,1.6-2.6c0.5-1,0.9-2.1,1.3-3.2l0.7-5.6c-0.5-0.6-1.1-1-1.8-1.2
     c-0.7-0.2-1.3-0.3-1.9-0.3c-1,0-1.9,0.3-2.7,0.9c-0.8,0.6-1.5,1.4-2.1,2.4c-0.6,1-1,2.1-1.3,3.4c-0.3,1.2-0.5,2.5-0.5,3.8
     c0,1.6,0.3,2.8,0.8,3.6C484.6,304.8,485.4,305.2,486.3,305.2z"/>
    <path class="st2" d="M520.6,309.3h-2.9c-0.7,0-1.2-0.2-1.4-0.5c-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.7-0.4-1.2l0.2-3.2c-1,1.6-2.2,2.9-3.5,3.8
     c-1.3,0.9-2.7,1.4-4.2,1.4c-0.9,0-1.7-0.2-2.5-0.5c-0.8-0.3-1.4-0.9-2-1.6c-0.6-0.7-1-1.5-1.3-2.6c-0.3-1-0.5-2.3-0.5-3.6
     c0-1.4,0.2-2.7,0.5-4.1c0.3-1.3,0.8-2.5,1.5-3.7c0.6-1.2,1.4-2.2,2.3-3.2c0.9-1,1.9-1.8,3-2.5c1.1-0.7,2.3-1.2,3.6-1.6
     c1.3-0.4,2.7-0.6,4.1-0.6c1,0,2.1,0.1,3.1,0.2c1,0.2,2.1,0.4,3.1,0.8L520.6,309.3z M510.5,305.1c0.6,0,1.2-0.2,1.8-0.6
     c0.6-0.4,1.2-1,1.7-1.8c0.5-0.8,1-1.6,1.5-2.6c0.5-1,0.8-2.1,1.2-3.3l0.9-7c-0.4,0-0.8-0.1-1.1-0.1c-1.3,0-2.4,0.3-3.5,0.9
     c-1.1,0.6-2,1.3-2.8,2.3c-0.8,1-1.4,2.1-1.8,3.4c-0.4,1.3-0.7,2.7-0.7,4.1c0,1.6,0.3,2.8,0.8,3.6
     C508.9,304.7,509.6,305.1,510.5,305.1z"/>
    <path class="st2" d="M526.1,309.3l4.1-33.7h5.5l-4.1,33.7H526.1z"/>
    <path class="st2" d="M544.4,315.7c-0.4,0.8-1,1.2-1.8,1.2h-4.1l5.2-9.4l-5.9-21.5h4.7c0.4,0,0.7,0.1,0.9,0.3
     c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.4,0.7l2.9,12.1c0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.2,1.2c0.1,0.4,0.1,0.8,0.1,1.2c0.2-0.4,0.3-0.8,0.5-1.2
     c0.2-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.5-1.2l5.7-12.1c0.2-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.7-0.7c0.3-0.2,0.6-0.3,0.9-0.3h4.5L544.4,315.7z"/>
     
   </g>
  </g>
  <g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <path class="st7" d="M896.5,346.9c0,2.6-2.1,4.8-4.7,4.8H713.2c-2.6,0-4.7-2.1-4.7-4.8V224.8c0-2.6,2.1-4.7,4.7-4.7h178.5
      c2.6,0,4.7,2.1,4.7,4.7V346.9z"/>
     <path class="st8" d="M896.5,346.9c0,2.6-2.1,4.8-4.7,4.8H713.2c-2.6,0-4.7-2.1-4.7-4.8V224.8c0-2.6,2.1-4.7,4.7-4.7h178.5
      c2.6,0,4.7,2.1,4.7,4.7V346.9z"/>
    </g>
    <rect x="719.5" y="231.1" class="st9" width="166" height="109.5"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M907.6,360.2c-46.3,0-157.1,0-210.3,0c-2.4,0-4.4-8.5-4.4-8.5H912C912,351.7,910,360.2,907.6,360.2z"/>
    <polygon class="st10" points="829.2,355.3 775.7,355.3 774.6,351.7 830.3,351.7     "/>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <path class="st11" d="M759.4,320.2c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-64.6c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v64.6
      C760.2,319.8,759.8,320.2,759.4,320.2z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
     <path class="st11" d="M849.7,320.2h-90.3c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h90.3c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9
      C850.5,319.8,850.1,320.2,849.7,320.2z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
     <path class="st11" d="M775.9,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-44c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v44
      C776.8,319.8,776.4,320.2,775.9,320.2z M767.4,318.5h7.6v-42.2h-7.6V318.5z"/>
    </g>
    <path class="st11" d="M791.8,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-62.4c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v62.4
     C792.7,319.8,792.3,320.2,791.8,320.2z M783.3,318.5h7.6v-60.7h-7.6V318.5z"/>
    <path class="st11" d="M807.7,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9V267c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v52.4
     C808.6,319.8,808.2,320.2,807.7,320.2z M799.2,318.5h7.6v-50.6h-7.6V318.5z"/>
    <path class="st11" d="M823.6,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-36.8c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v36.8
     C824.5,319.8,824.1,320.2,823.6,320.2z M815.1,318.5h7.6v-35h-7.6V318.5z"/>
    <path class="st11" d="M840.1,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-46.4c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v46.4
     C841,319.8,840.6,320.2,840.1,320.2z M831.6,318.5h7.6v-44.6h-7.6V318.5z"/>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Вы видите часть большого  круга  в углу,  когда все мелкие точки заканчивают анимацию, этот большой круг будет перемещаться по линии, находящейся между кругом логотипа и иконкой ноутбука.
Update: это самый последний вариант, который я пробовал, но я не знаю, какую часть я делаю неправильно, чтобы заставить этот синий круг двигаться.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/37349639/7394871

Answer (score 2):

- Для первой части анимации  верхний путь не имеет той же длины, что и
  другие, поэтому для движения точки по нему не потребуется то же самое
  время, что и для других точек.
- Во второй части я бы начал новую анимацию после того, как первая
  закончила использование `animationID.end` [begin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin) значение.

Вот как это могло бы выглядеть:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 970 570" enable-background="new 0 0 970 570" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>
    <style>
      path {
        stroke-dasharray: 1093.92, 1093.92;
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        transition-timing-function: linear;
        transition-duration: 2.5s;
        transition-delay: 0.5s;
        animation-duration: 2.5s;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <g>

      <path fill="none" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M164.2,101.8V242c0,11.9,9.7,21.6,21.6,21.6h282.1l35.9,31.6" id="path-to-trace-1"></path>
      <path fill="none" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M98.7,212v51.1c0,11.9,9.7,21.6,21.6,21.6h347.6l35.9,10.5" id="path-to-trace-2"></path>
      <path fill="none" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M280.7,165.9v70.3c0,4,3.2,7.2,7.2,7.2h180.1l35.9,51.8" id="path-to-trace-3"></path>
      <path fill="none" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M303.8,384.2v-29.4c0-4,3.2-7.2,7.2-7.2h156.9l35.9-52.4" id="path-to-trace-5"></path>
      <path fill="none" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M128.5,402.4V327c0-10.9,9.7-20.6,21.6-20.6h317.8l35.9-11.1" id="path-to-trace-6"></path>
      <path fill="none" stroke="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M0,0h204.6" id="last-path"></path>

      <line fill="none" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="440.3" y1="295.2" x2="819" y2="295.2"></line>

      <circle fill="#21A8E0" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
        <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto">
          <mpath xlink:href="#path-to-trace-1"></mpath>
        </animateMotion>
      </circle>
      <circle fill="#21A8E0" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
        <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto">
          <mpath xlink:href="#path-to-trace-2"></mpath>
        </animateMotion>
      </circle>
      <circle fill="#21A8E0" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
        <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto">
          <mpath xlink:href="#path-to-trace-3"></mpath>
        </animateMotion>
      </circle>
      <circle fill="#21A8E0" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
        <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto" id="smallCircle">
          <mpath xlink:href="#path-to-trace-5"></mpath>
        </animateMotion>
      </circle>
      <circle fill="#21A8E0" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
        <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto">
          <mpath xlink:href="#path-to-trace-6"></mpath>
        </animateMotion>
      </circle>
      <g>
        <circle fill="#6EC5E0" cx="503.9" cy="292" r="79.4"></circle>
        <g>
          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M478.4,276.5l-0.2,1.8c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.7c-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.5-0.4,0.7l-18.1,24.8h15.2l-0.6,4.7h-23
     l0.2-1.8c0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.7c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.5,0.4-0.7l18.2-24.9h-14.5l0.6-4.7H478.4z"></path>
          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M494,309.3c-0.7,0-1.2-0.2-1.4-0.5c-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.7-0.4-1.2l0.2-3.4c-1.1,1.7-2.4,3-3.8,4
     c-1.4,1-2.9,1.5-4.4,1.5c-1,0-1.8-0.2-2.6-0.5c-0.8-0.4-1.5-0.9-2-1.6c-0.6-0.7-1-1.6-1.3-2.7c-0.3-1.1-0.5-2.4-0.5-3.9
     c0-1.3,0.1-2.6,0.4-3.9c0.3-1.3,0.7-2.5,1.2-3.6c0.5-1.1,1.1-2.2,1.8-3.1c0.7-1,1.5-1.8,2.3-2.5c0.8-0.7,1.7-1.2,2.7-1.6
     c1-0.4,2-0.6,3-0.6c1,0,2,0.2,2.8,0.6c0.8,0.4,1.6,0.9,2.2,1.5l1.5-12.2h5.5l-4.1,33.7H494z M486.3,305.2c0.6,0,1.2-0.2,1.9-0.6
     c0.6-0.4,1.2-1,1.8-1.7c0.6-0.7,1.1-1.6,1.6-2.6c0.5-1,0.9-2.1,1.3-3.2l0.7-5.6c-0.5-0.6-1.1-1-1.8-1.2
     c-0.7-0.2-1.3-0.3-1.9-0.3c-1,0-1.9,0.3-2.7,0.9c-0.8,0.6-1.5,1.4-2.1,2.4c-0.6,1-1,2.1-1.3,3.4c-0.3,1.2-0.5,2.5-0.5,3.8
     c0,1.6,0.3,2.8,0.8,3.6C484.6,304.8,485.4,305.2,486.3,305.2z"></path>
          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M520.6,309.3h-2.9c-0.7,0-1.2-0.2-1.4-0.5c-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.7-0.4-1.2l0.2-3.2c-1,1.6-2.2,2.9-3.5,3.8
     c-1.3,0.9-2.7,1.4-4.2,1.4c-0.9,0-1.7-0.2-2.5-0.5c-0.8-0.3-1.4-0.9-2-1.6c-0.6-0.7-1-1.5-1.3-2.6c-0.3-1-0.5-2.3-0.5-3.6
     c0-1.4,0.2-2.7,0.5-4.1c0.3-1.3,0.8-2.5,1.5-3.7c0.6-1.2,1.4-2.2,2.3-3.2c0.9-1,1.9-1.8,3-2.5c1.1-0.7,2.3-1.2,3.6-1.6
     c1.3-0.4,2.7-0.6,4.1-0.6c1,0,2.1,0.1,3.1,0.2c1,0.2,2.1,0.4,3.1,0.8L520.6,309.3z M510.5,305.1c0.6,0,1.2-0.2,1.8-0.6
     c0.6-0.4,1.2-1,1.7-1.8c0.5-0.8,1-1.6,1.5-2.6c0.5-1,0.8-2.1,1.2-3.3l0.9-7c-0.4,0-0.8-0.1-1.1-0.1c-1.3,0-2.4,0.3-3.5,0.9
     c-1.1,0.6-2,1.3-2.8,2.3c-0.8,1-1.4,2.1-1.8,3.4c-0.4,1.3-0.7,2.7-0.7,4.1c0,1.6,0.3,2.8,0.8,3.6
     C508.9,304.7,509.6,305.1,510.5,305.1z"></path>
          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M526.1,309.3l4.1-33.7h5.5l-4.1,33.7H526.1z"></path>
          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M544.4,315.7c-0.4,0.8-1,1.2-1.8,1.2h-4.1l5.2-9.4l-5.9-21.5h4.7c0.4,0,0.7,0.1,0.9,0.3
     c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.4,0.7l2.9,12.1c0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.2,1.2c0.1,0.4,0.1,0.8,0.1,1.2c0.2-0.4,0.3-0.8,0.5-1.2
     c0.2-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.5-1.2l5.7-12.1c0.2-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.7-0.7c0.3-0.2,0.6-0.3,0.9-0.3h4.5L544.4,315.7z"></path>
        </g>
        <animateMotion begin="smallCircle.end-0.5s" dur="4s" calcMode="linear" id="bigCircle">
          <mpath xlink:href="#last-path"></mpath>
        </animateMotion>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g>
      <g>
        <path fill="#21A8E0" d="M139.5,201.8c0,11-9,20-20,20H78c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h41.6c11,0,20,9,20,20V201.8z"></path>
      </g>
      <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 80.6445 205.3301)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Lato-Light'" font-size="16px">Trade</text>
      <g>
        <path fill="#21A8E0" d="M213.1,425.8c0,11-9,20-20,20h-92.1c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h92.1c11,0,20,9,20,20V425.8z"></path>
      </g>
      <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 110.1387 429.3643)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Lato-Light'" font-size="16px">Derivatives</text>
      <g>
        <path fill="#21A8E0" d="M359.7,146.8c0,11-9,20-20,20H218c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h121.7c11,0,20,9,20,20V146.8z"></path>
      </g>
      <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 220.1895 150.3301)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Lato-Light'" font-size="16px">Macro-economics</text>
      <g>
        <path fill="#21A8E0" d="M250.6,83c0,11-9,20-20,20H97.8c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h132.9c11,0,20,9,20,20V83z"></path>
      </g>
      <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 101.3477 86.4922)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Lato-Light'" font-size="16px">Supply v/s demand</text>
      <g>
        <path fill="#21A8E0" d="M307.5,491.5c0,11-9,20-20,20H165.7c-11,0-20-9-20-20V487c0-11,9-20,20-20h121.7c11,0,20,9,20,20V491.5z"></path>
      </g>
      <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 167.916 495.042)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Lato-Light'" font-size="16px">Financial markets</text>
      <g>
        <path fill="#21A8E0" d="M367.4,408.7c0,11-9,20-20,20h-84.8c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h84.8c11,0,20,9,20,20V408.7z"></path>
      </g>
      <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 267.4238 412.1934)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Lato-Light'" font-size="16px">Geo politics</text>
      <g>
        <g>
          <g>
            <path fill="#DDE9F1" d="M896.5,346.9c0,2.6-2.1,4.8-4.7,4.8H713.2c-2.6,0-4.7-2.1-4.7-4.8V224.8c0-2.6,2.1-4.7,4.7-4.7h178.5
      c2.6,0,4.7,2.1,4.7,4.7V346.9z"></path>

            <path fill="none" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
      M896.5,346.9c0,2.6-2.1,4.8-4.7,4.8H713.2c-2.6,0-4.7-2.1-4.7-4.8V224.8c0-2.6,2.1-4.7,4.7-4.7h178.5c2.6,0,4.7,2.1,4.7,4.7
      V346.9z"></path>
          </g>

          <rect x="719.5" y="231.1" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="166" height="109.5"></rect>

          <path fill="#FAFBFC" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
     M907.6,360.2c-46.3,0-157.1,0-210.3,0c-2.4,0-4.4-8.5-4.4-8.5H912C912,351.7,910,360.2,907.6,360.2z"></path>

          <polygon fill="#FAFBFC" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
     829.2,355.3 775.7,355.3 774.6,351.7 830.3,351.7     "></polygon>
        </g>
        <g>
          <g>
            <path fill="#303D4F" d="M759.4,320.2c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-64.6c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v64.6
      C760.2,319.8,759.8,320.2,759.4,320.2z"></path>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path fill="#303D4F" d="M849.7,320.2h-90.3c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h90.3c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9
      C850.5,319.8,850.1,320.2,849.7,320.2z"></path>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path fill="#303D4F" d="M775.9,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-44c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v44
      C776.8,319.8,776.4,320.2,775.9,320.2z M767.4,318.5h7.6v-42.2h-7.6V318.5z"></path>
          </g>
          <path fill="#303D4F" d="M791.8,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-62.4c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v62.4
     C792.7,319.8,792.3,320.2,791.8,320.2z M783.3,318.5h7.6v-60.7h-7.6V318.5z"></path>
          <path fill="#303D4F" d="M807.7,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9V267c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v52.4
     C808.6,319.8,808.2,320.2,807.7,320.2z M799.2,318.5h7.6v-50.6h-7.6V318.5z"></path>
          <path fill="#303D4F" d="M823.6,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-36.8c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v36.8
     C824.5,319.8,824.1,320.2,823.6,320.2z M815.1,318.5h7.6v-35h-7.6V318.5z"></path>
          <path fill="#303D4F" d="M840.1,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-46.4c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v46.4
     C841,319.8,840.6,320.2,840.1,320.2z M831.6,318.5h7.6v-44.6h-7.6V318.5z"></path>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M708.5,295.2"></path>
</svg>
```

Источник: [SVG animateMotion duration not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37361011/7394871) @Kaiido